# Zip two or more numbers together bitwise

Tags: c, math, binary

What is the best way to zip two (or more) numbers' bit representations together in C/C++/Obj-C?

I have num one to three. Their binary representations are [abc, ABC, xyz]. I would like to produce a num with binary [aAxbBycCz]. I'm mainly working with numbers that are over 21 bits.

(Ignoring the limit on integers, endian-ness and whatnot).

Thanks, happy holidays guys :)

Comment: How could their binary representations be `abc, ABC, xyz`?  Binary is `0` and `1`.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think each of the letters `a,b,c,A,B,C,x,y,z` are variables representing single bits.

Comment: @self Because it is not known beforehand which value each variable will take.

Comment: @Chad sorry for the confusion that caused. I merely meant for them to represent unknown values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that should work for any number of bits:

```
const unsigned int BITS = 21;
unsigned int zipper(unsigned a0, unsigned a1, unsigned a2)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for (unsigned int mask = 1<<BITS; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
    {
        result |= a0 & mask;
        result <<= 1;
        result |= a1 & mask;
        result <<= 1;
        result |= a2 & mask;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: By eyeballing, not testing: does this not need an initial `result <<= 1;` at the top of the loop? You are inserting 3 bits but make only room for two.

Comment: @Jongware Look carefully at where the bit is inserted. That job is accomplished by bit shifting `mask` at the end on each iteration.

Comment: A-ha. The 'last' bit doesn't need shifting, it fits in its original position. You only need to make room for the two incoming bits. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

If you need more speed, do some precalculation:

```
static unsigned explode[]= { 0, 1, 0x1000, 0x1001, 0x1000000, 0x1000001, 0x1001000, 0x1001001 } ;

unsigned int zipper(unsigned a0, unsigned a1, unsigned a2)
{
  return explode[a0] | ( explode[a1] << 1) | ( explode[a2] << 2 ) ;
}
```

With the usual caveats for out of bounds, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the numbers i'm zipping are between 0 and 1 million (21 bit max), so this is indeed a really really good solution for small numbers, but not so much here if i have to make a 8MB precalculated chunk...

Comment: @Xrave Please update your question to make it clear that you want a solution that scales to larger number of bits. Both woolstar and I interpreted your question to mean that your inputs are only three bits.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it by brute force:

```c
unsigned int binaryZip(unsigned int a0, unsigned int a1, unsigned int a2)
{
    return ((a0 << 0) & 0x001) |
           ((a1 << 1) & 0x002) |
           ((a2 << 2) & 0x004) |
           ((a0 << 2) & 0x008) |
           ((a1 << 3) & 0x010) |
           ((a2 << 4) & 0x020) |
           ((a0 << 4) & 0x040) |
           ((a1 << 5) & 0x080) |
           ((a2 << 6) & 0x100);
}
```